# Как добавить в дерево родственика WPF C# DevExpress

Tags: c#, wpf, devexpress

Мне нужно сделать так, чтобы можно было добавлять в дерево "брата", но только выше или ниже. Работаю из `devexpress` компонентом.

Описание как это происходит:

Когда нажимаю на выбранный элемент правой кнопкой мышки - выводится бар меню, в котором есть добавить РЕБЁНКА, добавить БРАТА, но перед или после выбранным элементом.

Я сделал добавление БРАТА, но не могу добавлять перед ним или после него.

Как можно решить эту проблему?

С# - код, который добавляет брата в дерево:

```
  private void AddBeforeBarItem_OnItemClick(object sender, ItemClickEventArgs e)
    {

        var newItem = new FundusTreeItemViewModel
        {
            Id = _tmpCount,
            ParentId = 0,
            IsActiveGrid = false,

            Name = "Neue"
        };
        _tmpCount -= 1;

        if (treeListControl != null && treeListControl.SelectedItems.Count != 0)
        {
            var parent = treeListControl.SelectedItems[0] as IFundusTreeItemViewModel;
            if (parent != null)
                newItem.ParentId = parent.ParentId;
        }

        _items.Add(newItem);
    }
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Нужно найти индекс и его заменить на `index + 1` если после выбраного елемента и `index - 1` если перед выбраним елементом

```
var index = _items.IndexOf(parent);
            _items.Insert(index + 1, newItem);
```